# Deploy react project to Heroku without source code showing?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a react project I am trying to deploy to heroku. I did so by installing the [react buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) however when I go to the website, open inspect element, all my client side source code is simply exposed to all public view. What am I doing wrong, I cannot find any help which addresses this issue but it is quite the security flaw. Help me understand, because I know I did something wrong and it should not be this way. Thanks!

[image: All the files of my project when you open dev tools and go to sources]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the build script to include `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` so that the build commands follow it. This is an intended effect according to [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1632)

[gaearon](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1632#issuecomment-282287745)

> This is expected. You can delete `.map` files from the build output if
> you want to disable it, although you'll get console warnings about
> them missing.
>
> There is no harm in leaving them in though in my opinion. Client code
> is already available to the user’s machine so there’s no secrets in
> it.

```
scripts: {
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
}
```